# Как проверить, есть ли значение переменной в списке полученном из динамического запроса?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic

В функции пытаюсь проверить, есть ли значение параметра в списке полученном из динамического запроса, но безуспешно. Не смог найти подходящий для этого синтаксис.

Пробую создать табличный тип данных и функцию так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TP_BI_LIST AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckDataMissing (pOwn VARCHAR2, pTab VARCHAR2, pCol VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_str VARCHAR2(2000); 
    v_Results TP_BI_LIST := TP_BI_LIST();
BEGIN
    v_str := 'SELECT ''TEST1'' AS NM_COLUMN FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT ''TEST2'' AS NM_COLUMN FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT ''TEST3'' AS NM_COLUMN FROM DUAL';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str into v_Results;
   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total rows: '||v_Results.COUNT);       

    IF pCol IN (v_Results) THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('YES'); 
    ELSE dbms_output.put_line('NO'); 
    END IF;       
  
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END CheckDataMissing;
/
```

Но это не работает, получаю ошибку:

> 12/8      PLS-00383: type mismatch found at 'PCOL' inside an IN or NOT IN clause

Какой есть путь решения?

Также пробовал решения в этих темах: [PL/SQL - Use “List” Variable in Where In Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232045/10176057), [How to pass varchar with single quotes to Stored Proc in Oracle [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799087/10176057) и [How to add values to a VARRAY using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39638630/10176057), но безуспешно.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL Check if a variable is in a list from Execute Immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61826840) от участника [Guilherme Matheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10176057/guilherme-matheus)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61826840

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить коллекцию из запроса надо, либо воспользоваться [BULK COLLECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-19F50644-C88E-49AF-B31C-3EE4B4432714) клаузой, либо создать коллекцию функцией [COLLECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLLECT.html#GUID-A0A74602-2A97-449B-A3EC-847D38D3DA90). Чтобы узнать, есть ли элемент с заданным значением в коллекции, надо воспользоваться условным оператором [MEMBER [OF]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/operations-on-collection-data-types.html#GUID-7B34CDAD-CF7D-4BBF-90DE-338527A18B84).

Воспроизводимый пример, как надо сделать:

```
create or replace type listofcols as table of varchar2 (4000)
/
create or replace function isFound (col varchar2) return char is
    guery varchar2 (2000); 
    Results listofcols;
    ret char (1);
begin
    guery := q'[
        select cast (collect (trim (col)) as listofcols) from ( 
            select 'TEST1' col from dual union all
            select 'TEST2'     from dual union all
            select 'TEST3'     from dual)]';
    execute immediate guery into Results;

    if Col member of Results then ret := 'y';
    else ret := 'n'; 
    end if;  
    dbms_output.put_line ('isFound('||col||')='||ret||': total '||Results.count||' rows'); 
    return ret;
end isFound;
/
```

Результат:

```
var res char (1)  
exec :res := isFound (upper ('test2'));

isFound(TEST2)=y: total 3 rows

RES
---
y
```